# Access data class programatically with variables in a loop kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Is there a way to programatically access the parameters of a `data class` in kotlin?

```
data class Foo(
    val a: Int,
    val b: Double,
    val c: Boolean,
    val d: String,
) {
    fun doubleA(): Int {
        return (a * 2)
    }
}

val something = Foo(1, 58.1, true, "Hey There")

val parameters = listOf("a", "b", "c", "d")
for (parameter in parameters) {
    -> Access "something" with "parameter"
}
```

Comment: FOO().parameters  did you try that ?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What problem are you trying to solve? As cactustictacs's answer indicates, it's not a good fit in a strongly-typed language like Kotlin; in practice, there are usually better approaches (though it's hard to suggest anything without knowing more of the big picture in this case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Reflection feature to do that at The Runtime

```kotlin
fun accessDataClassPropertyByName(clazz: Any, name: String): Any? {
    return clazz::class.members.firstOrNull { it.name == name }?.call(clazz)
}

fun main() {
    val something = Foo(1, 58.1, true, "Hey There")
    val parameters = listOf("a", "b", "c", "d")
    for (parameter in parameters) {
        println(accessDataClassPropertyByName(something, parameter))
    }
}
```

Output

```
1
58.1
true
Hey There
```

Another solution is to create an Annotation Processor that generates a class with function or function extensions at compile time to take string and call the property, you need to generate extension like this

```kotlin
fun Foo.accessWithName(name : String) : Any? {
    return when (name) {
        "a" -> a
        "b" -> b
        "c" -> c
        "d" -> d
        else -> null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Outside of reflection no, the only special thing a data class provides is a bunch of `componentN` functions that accesses the properties in the order they're declared. This is what's used to do [destructuring declarations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/destructuring-declarations.html), so you could do this if you want:

```
val (a, b, c, d) = something
val parameters = listOf(a, b, c, d)
```

Really that's reading each property into a local `val`, then creating a list from all those values, so it's not super efficient or anything - but it's concise, if it's what you want to do! Also this is effectively read-only since you're just reading the current values of those properties into a list - you don't have references to *the properties themselves* in your loop, so if you wanted to do things like updating the values in the data class, this isn't the way to go.

You *could* do something like that programmatically with reflection - but at that point, you need to ask if this the right way to do whatever you're trying to do. This approach is basically stepping outside the type system - you're creating a general list of *stuff* instead of the structured data the data class provides. Maybe that's the right call! Or maybe you want to stay within the type system, and explicitly write code to handle each data class specifically, e.g. creating a *sealed class* hierarchy of all the data classes you need to handle. It really depends on what you're doing though!